# Where should i place logic for database column calculation

Tags: sql-server, design-patterns, database-design

I using MS SQL Server with C# and Entity Framework.

The data-tier have one repository for every table that handle Save, Delete, Get etc.
Then i have a business layer that helps the user interface with data transactions and error handling and so on.

In one of the column in database i need to do a calculation before save.
Should i override the Add/Update method in the data-tier and do this calculation or should this be placed in business tier.

Thanks in advice.

Comment: (1) if it's a simple calculation - why even bother to store the result? Calculate it as needed. (2) if it's a rather simple calculation but you want to store the result - look at **computed columns** on the database level. (3) If it's rather complex and cannot be easily expressed in T-SQL, then I would calculate it in the business tier in C# and store the resulting value as a "regular" column in your SQL Server table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a fine grained, well scaled application design, respecting to standard specifications AKA [SOA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service-oriented_architecture), any entity has its own service(business) layer and persist layer objects.
When User-interface layer calls a service, the service is receiving a simple or composite DTO that may be mapped to one or more separated database entities, it is allowed in service layer to call other entities service, and you are not allowed to call other entities persist layer objects.
Following the approach:
If the calculation of property `A1` in entity `A` **is based on properties of entity `A`** then you **may** do the calculation on persist layer.
 If The calculation of property `A1` in entity `A` **is based on other entities properties** then you **have to** do the calculation in service layer.